# How to override password verification in ServiceStack?

Tags: servicestack

I have some people who login through standard ServiceStack authentication and some people whose passwords need to be compared to Active Directory. They use the same `CredentialsAuthProvider` and I want to be able to make use of the stuff happening in `OrmLiteAuthRepository.TryAuthenticateAsync` (recording of invalid login attempts etc.).

My solution thus far:

```
    public class MyOrmLiteAuthRepository : OrmLiteAuthRepository
{
    public override async Task<IUserAuth?> TryAuthenticateAsync(string userName, string password,
        CancellationToken token = new CancellationToken())
    {
        if (!IsActiveDirectoryLogin)
        {
            return await base.TryAuthenticateAsync(userName, password, token);
        }

        var userAuth = await GetUserAuthByUserNameAsync(userName, token).ConfigAwait();

        if (userAuth == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        if (IsValidActiveDirectoryCredentials())
        {
            await this.RecordSuccessfulLoginAsync(userAuth, false, password, token).ConfigAwait();
            return userAuth;
        }

        await this.RecordInvalidLoginAttemptAsync(userAuth, token).ConfigAwait();
    }
}
```

So I have to repeat all the calls in the base leaving room for problems if ServiceStack changes. If IUserAuth.VerifyPassword wasn't an extension method and virtual I would've overridden it and placed the same conditional logic in there.

Is there a more straight forward way to override the password checking?

Answer (score 1):

The standard way is to [create a Custom CredentialsAuthProvider](https://docs.servicestack.net/authentication-and-authorization#custom-authentication-and-authorization), e.g:

```cs
public class CustomCredentialsAuthProvider : CredentialsAuthProvider
{
    public override async Task<bool> TryAuthenticateAsync(IServiceBase authService, 
        string userName, string password, CancellationToken token=default)
    {
        //Add here your custom auth logic (database calls etc)
        //Return true if credentials are valid, otherwise false
    }
}
```

That you would register in your `AuthFeature` plugin instead.

Comment: I have created a Custom provider. But I was asking if there was a way I could still use the full Servicestack pipeline but verify the password in a different way. Because the UserAuth exists, only with an unused password. 

I suppose I could write my own PasswordHasher and place the logic in VerifyPassword there, but that doesn’t feel like the right place to do this.

Comment: @glazjoon Yeah if you want to change the password verification itself you would register a custom `IPasswordHasher` in the IOC.